# How can you host firebase functions and a single-page application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a single-page application using React.js. My team and I are set on utilizing Firebase Hosting to the best of our abilities and are trying to deploy our application. My issue is that I am trying to deploy both the static site and functions, the only issue is that I cannot host the both of them with my current configuration. This is the `firebase.json` that I am using though it does not show the function at `/helloWorld`, only the static site.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/helloWorld",
        "function": "helloWorld"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want it to route to the `helloWorld` function when I go to `/helloWorld`, and route it to the static `index.html` file when I go to any route other than `/helloWorld`. This is an example **if I were was Express.js**.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/helloWorld', (req, res) => {
  res.send('this is a cloud function');
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('this is the static site');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I actually don't think this is possible with functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it well, you simply want to redirect your users to `index.html` when they try to reach `www.yourwebiste.com/**` (where `**` can be anything else than `helloWrold`) and show *helloWorld* page only when they try to reach `www.yourwebsite.com/helloWorld`

Right?

If yes, than here's how I would do it:

**firebase.json**

```
...
"rewrites": [
  {
   "source": "/helloWorld/**", 
   "function": "helloWorld"
  }
]
```

There's no need to add

```
{
  "source": "**",
  "function": "/index.html"
}
```

because it's the default redirection.

Then in your js file

```
const express = require("express");
const redirection = express();

redirection.route('/helloWorld')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('this is my redirected page')
  })
```

Comment: This looks interesting, so basically I only would route to my functions and the rest of the requests go to `index.html`?

Comment: @NathanielFredericks, hmm... you mean if you try to reach `www.yourwebiste.com/helloWorld/something` ? If you do so, with the code I provided you will be redirected to `/helloWorld` because the firebase.json file contains `source: /helloWorld/**` pay attention to the `**` which means all path that begin with `/helloWorld/...`

Comment: is there a reason why it is not only `/helloWorld`?

Comment: If you write `source: /helloWorld` than only `www.yourwebsite.com/helloWorld` will be redirected and **all** the other paths will be redirected to index.html